# Estimation of time for a specific value of a variable

Tags: r, expectation-maximization, splines, interpolation, kriging

I have a data set:

```
require(xts)
days<-seq(as.Date("2016-05-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2016-07-31", format="%Y-%m-%d" ), by= 1)
df.days<-xts(x = data.frame(Empty=rep(NA, length(days))), order.by=days)
df.norm <- rnorm(10000, 40, 5)
df.norm <- df.norm[df.norm > 30 & df.norm < 50]
SAMPLE <-sample(df.norm, length(df.days[.indexwday(df.days)==1]), replace=FALSE) 
df.weeks<-xts(SAMPLE, order.by = index(df.days[.indexwday(df.days)==1]))
df.data<-merge.xts(df.weeks,df.days)
df.data<-df.data[,1]
colnames(df.data)[1]<-"variable1"
```

Now suppose we do not the true distribution of the variable1 but its underlying process tends to approach 40 over days.

> I want to know at what date the variable1 will be equal to 40.

What is the best  method applicable to this case?

Some options I can think of are Spline, Expectation Maximization, and probably Kriging. Kindly help me do this in R.

Answer (score 1):

Expectation-Maximisation is a method for optimizing parameters, rather than interpolation. As to whether to use kriging or spline interpolation, I would suggest that splines are perhaps conceptually simpler and a better first port of call.

The easiest option, in my opinion, is to use the loess() function from the core package, which is nicely documented (use: `?loess` in RStudio to see the documentation). Loess has a width parameter which needs to be specified, which can be optimised through generalised cross validation. The documentation should contain enough example code to get you moving.

For some example code and a discussion of the limits of LOESS regression, maybe read: http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/07/24/whats-wrong-with-loess-for-palaeo-data/

Comment: Thanks for help. Is it also possible to do kriging on my data?

Comment: In principle, yes, though you'd have to think about how to use it with your dataframe. If your aim is simply to find a smooth function underlying your data and using this to predict additional points, many regression methods will be suitable. These typically come with some governing assumptions, so make sure you are clear on what those are. For a very general introduction to krigingsee Rasmussen and Williams' textbook Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, which is freely available online.

Comment: Please see the question again. I have edited it.

Comment: Kindly See my edited question. The focus of this question is what You have just answered.

Comment: How do I apply the concept we just discussed to this data?